# Variable Position Sizing: Equity Curve vs Buy & Hold

Tags: equities, algorithmic-trading, equity-curve

I have a trading strategy that can take multiple long positions with different sizes before selling them. For example, buy 5 shares of ABC on days 1, 2, 3 and sell 15 on day 4. Going forward, buy 10 shares on days, 11, 12, 13 and sell 30 shares on day 14 etc. I can plot equity curve for this strategy. But, I don’t know how to fairly plot equity curve for the corresponding buy and hold strategy for the sake of comparing against market. Any comment/suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just buy an amount of shares of SPY in a test account that has same dollar value as the ABC shares you bought in the main account the same day. When you completely liquidate the ABC shares you also completely liquidate the SPY shares. At the end plot the performance of both accounts.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was very helpful.

Comment: @noob2 another quick follow up question. What if ABC is infact SPY i.e. testing the strategy on SPY itself rather than stock(s)? Following your approach, the two plots would be the same which I think is not sensible. I migth me wrong though.

Comment: That's a different problem, market timing or switching in and out of the market. For that randomization (i.e. comparing yourself to someone who switches in and out similarly, but at random ) could be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies.